# How to Implement RPKI for our network?

Tags: security, routes, cloudflare, ca, bgp

I read a few articles and some docs in various forums but I didn't get any clarity about it.

Are there any methods do I have to follow to implement RPKI-BGP in my network. Please help

Comment: "Network Engineering" would be a better community for this question; it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

"Deploying BGP Routing Security" is an excellent book that describes in detail how to deploy RPKI.

It is available for free (with registration) at https://www.juniper.net/uk/en/training/jnbooks/day-one/deploying-bgp-routing-security/ or for $0.99 on Amazon.